# Localization not working in culture fr in XamarinForms PCL

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have tried to localize the Xamarin Forms application from PCL project , resource file get localized for culture (en-US,ta,de,ja) but French culture (fr or fr-FR) not localizing , checked in XamrinForms.UWP and XamarinForms.Android.

Referred:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization?tabs=vswin#platform-specific-code

Please share your suggestion.

Regards,
Jeyasri M